# How do I construct the JSON data with session info for creating node?

Tags: 7, services

I am using Drupal 7 and the Services module 7.x-3.2. I am using [Postman for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) (a http client) to test the API.

What I want to do is log in a user and create a node with the user using the Drupal service API.

I logged in the user with JSON POST request to http://example.com/api/user/login.

> [image]

I successfully got the JSON result.

```
{
    "sessid": "KrZjlcY3rFr8v6iLoskcVQN9DmDWsg5yZqIjBeydEBY",
    "session_name": "SESS9fe39db36ccd7afd64e034fefa0129e1",
    "user": {
        "uid": "31",
        "name": "test_user",
        "mail": "services_user_2@example.com",
        "theme": "",
        "signature": "",
        "signature_format": "filtered_html",
        "created": "1352985941",
        "access": "1352991170",
        "login": 1352991510,
        "status": "1",
        "timezone": "",
        "language": "",
        "picture": null,
        "init": "services_user_2@example.com",
        "data": false,
        "roles": {
            "2": "authenticated user"
        },
        "rdf_mapping": {
            "rdftype": [
                "sioc:UserAccount"
            ],
            "name": {
                "predicates": [
                    "foaf:name"
                ]
            },
            "homepage": {
                "predicates": [
                    "foaf:page"
                ],
                "type": "rel"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to create an article via the API by sending the JSON POST request. (The user has the permission to create *Article* nodes.)

> [image]

I got a *401 Unauthorized* response.

I guess I need to include the session cookie information to send the POST request, to create a node.

I have the session information previously returned.

```
"sessid": "KrZjlcY3rFr8v6iLoskcVQN9DmDWsg5yZqIjBeydEBY",
"session_name": "SESS9fe39db36ccd7afd64e034fefa0129e1",
```

How can I utilize it to make a successful JSON POST request for creating a node?

Answer (score 2):

```
{
   "title": "Just another drupal Post",
   "type": "Article"
}
```

notice no comma after the type:article tag so that your json works.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you,

- To make the HTTP requests, Im using the Firefox add-on [POSTER](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/).

  [image]

  ```
  {
    "type" : "article",
    "title" : "Test article with language",
    "language" : "und"
  }
  ```
- If node is created successfully you will get a response with a link.

  [image]
- Examples

  `{
    "type": "article",
    "title": "Test article",
    "body": { 
      "und": [{ 
        "value": "test body!"
       }]
    },
    "language" : "und"
  }`


  `{
     "title":"Review",
     "type":"establishment_review",
     "field_establishment":[
        {
           "nid":{
              "nid":"[nid:26686]"
           }
        }
     ],
     "field_fivestar_value":[
        {
           "rating":"20",
           "target":"0"
        }
     ],
     "field_review":[
        {
           "value":"comments about the restaurant"
        }
     ]
  }`
- You can refer [this](https://drupal.org/node/1354202)
- I have answered [How do I POST a new node using the Services module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77256/how-do-i-post-a-new-node-using-the-services-module/77552#77552) question. You can refer for more information.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `cookie="sessionname=sessionid"` value in headers, where sessionname comes from the endpoint/user/login URL.