# Register User with Services (JSON) with Custom Fields

Tags: 7, users, services

I am trying to register a new user on Drupal7 via services with JSON. Actually I am posting info from JAVA (android) with JSON format to the server with services module enabled. A sample successful JSON post is:

```
    {
    "name": "erfan",
    "pass": "1234",
    "mail": "erfan@example.com",
    "status": "1"
     }
```

> **URL:** [siteURL]/[endpoint]/user/register

I was successful creating users with basic info such as name,email,status.

I have added custom fields like `field_address`, `field_phone`, etc to the web site and want to send them via JSON to the server.

The problem is I can not figure out how to post these data to the server and couldn't find any documentation about it. My trial and error approach was not successful too, because I am not good in PHP coding. So please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add one of the attempts? It'll be a bit easier to advise once we've seen the code. Entity fields are structured like `$account->field_name[$language][$delta][$column_name]` if that helps. An example for a text field might be `$account->field_foo[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']`

Comment: I added more details about my problem. I am not a PHP expert. :)

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can use the below **JSON format** to add custom fields(`field_user_image`)

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "pass": "password",
    "mail": "test@gmail.com",
    "field_user_image": {
        "und": [{
            "fid": "2"
        }]
    }
}
```

I have tried in my local and it is working fine.

- Created new field **UUID**

  [image]
- Calling the Service using **[Firefox poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/)** add-on

  [image]
- Code

```
  { 
    "name": "testuser123", 
    "pass": "testuser123", 
    "mail": "testuser123@gmail.com", 
    "field_register_uuid": 
      { "und": 
        [{ 
          "value": "65C7DCA4-8F03-473C-9E8F-08B3F29E91AE" 
        }] 
      }
  }
```

I can able to create new user with the custom field

References

- [How do I POST a new node using the Services module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77256/how-do-i-post-a-new-node-using-the-services-module/77552#77552)
- [Services module. How to construct the JSON data with session info for creating node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50559/services-module-how-to-construct-the-json-data-with-session-info-for-creating-n/77811#77811)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm using UUID Field, and want to create a user with a UUID, which is just a text field, really. { "name": "test", "pass": "password", "mail": "test@gmail.com", "field_uuid": { "und": [{ "uuid_field": "65C7DCA4-8F03-473C-9E8F-08B3F29E91AE" }] }} https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/Mile23/1326218

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But nope. :-) I suppose it's something to do with the way authentication is happening, or some other configuration problem.

Comment: I discovered I can create the user and then use PUT to update the field. The JSON above is correct, but it has to be a 2-step process. https://www.drupal.org/node/790416

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment, but I haven't enough reputation ...
When you create a user, you can only pass the fields that are shown in the registration form. Otherwise you'll need first to register the user and then update it with the new fields, as @paul-m said in his comment.

To show a field in the registration form go to

> configuration->people->account settings-> manage fields
>   click the edit
>   link of the desired field and check "Display on user registration
>   form."

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. Your answer in fact does contribute to the original question, so I would recommend you to re-format it and improve it.

Comment: At the time of writing this answer probably it was not possible to update custom fields in one go, but now https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/156404/11058 answer works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The field value may have to be "flattened" in order for the user registration to work. In the example below, the field is a `List (text)` field with **radio buttons** for the widget.

- **POST** `?q=[my-endpoint]/user/register.json`
- **Content-Type**: `application/json`

JSON data to *POST*:

```
{
  "name":"bob",
  "mail":"bob@gmail.com",
  "conf_mail":"bob@gmail.com",
  "pass":"secret",
  "pass2":"secret",
  "field_choices":"2"
}
```

This also works for radio buttons:

```
"field_choices":{"und":"a"}
```

However, when we use a **select list** widget on this same field, the JSON is formed like this:

```
"field_choices":{"und":[{"value":"2"}]}
```

The JSON above will not work for radio buttons, you'll get a `406 - Not Acceptable An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator`. This is a lesson and reminder that the Services module can sometimes be dependant on your field's widget when it comes to the JSON it expects.

Comment: is it possible to modify the response. {
    "uid": "9",
    "uri": "http://example.com/food_api/user/9"
}

Comment: @Smalution Yes, use this hook: `hook_services_request_postprocess_alter()` - http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/docs/services.alter.api.php?h=7.x-3.x