# 401 Unauthorized : Missing required argument node

Tags: nodes, organic-groups, services, 8

I am trying to Create Services to Create Node Type Discussion in a Group using Services Module, but getting the error : 401 Unauthorized : Missing required argument node

In the Header I have given:

> Content-type:application/json
>
> x-csrf-token:token value
>
> session-name:session name value

In the Body I have given :

```
{
"og_group_ref": {"und": [{"target_id": "3897"}]},

"title": "Title of discussion",

"field_description": {"und": [{"value": "test description"}]},

"type": "discussion",

}
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error ?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: possible same question that may help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50559/services-module-how-to-construct-the-json-data-with-session-info-for-creating-n/77811#77811

Comment: Try this: `{"node":{"og_group_ref": {"und": [{"target_id": "3897"}]},"title": "Title of discussion","field_description": {"und": [{"value": "test description"}]},"type": "discussion"}}`

Comment: Didn't worked. I am getting this error : 500 Internal Server Error : An error occurred(0): Unknown data property field_group_privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put comma on last parameter `"type": "discussion",` that doesn't required at the end. javascript, jquery, json doesn't allow comma at end of array. It returns invalid argument.

Comment: Thanks for you help but now I am getting

> 500 internal Server Error : An error occurred(0): Unknown data property field_group_privacy.

Comment: you didn't add field_group_privacy field here? Are you missing or parameter is wrong i am not getting?

Comment: Do I need to add this on body ?
"field_group_privacy":{"und":[{"value": "0"}]}

Comment: first of all you need to call get node service where actually you get what properties you need to pass in body. Just call http://drupal.org/endpoint/node/123.json and click on GET in poster.

Comment: Yes, I checked it but there no property with the name of field_group_privacy ? This field look like a field of Group but I am creating Discussion within a Group

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your data like so:

```
{
  node: {
    type: 'discussion',
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked. I am getting this error : 500 Internal Server Error : An error occurred(0): Unknown data property field_group_privacy.

Comment: Usually a 500 means you have a syntax error somewhere up in PHP in Drupal. From the error, it looks like someone is trying to access `field_group_privacy` on an entity without verifying it `isset()` first.